# Superhot Fullscreen

Tags: superhot

5 inch display. I have recently purchased super hot and there is no way to get it into full screen. I have tried changing resolution but it doesn't work please help.

Comment: Obviously the modern answer is to play it in VR. Once you try it on something like an Oculus Rift you will never go back.

Answer (score 3):

Simply press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, like in most Mac apps.

Comment: Thank you so much it was such a simple fix but made a hug difference.